connecting from localhost Laravel website to Hostinger shared hosting MySQL database is too slow
Connecting from localhost Laravel website to Hostinger shared hosting MySQL database is too slow.. it takes around 20 seconds to load login page. What can be the problem and how to solve it.
I also allow firewall on port 3306. Still not working. Taking too much time to load any page.

Slow connection speed, high ping, network throtling, bandwith ...  too many reasons for that. First of all make sure that the hosting is in the same region from where you're trying to connect to lower the ping. There's not much you can do about it
